# Rails: Single Record, Many Polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

*I'm sure there is a better title for this, so sorry about that.*

I've got a `Verification` model. Ideally, there would various other model types that are able to associate themselves with the a single `Verification` record. For instance.

- `Verification(id: 1, verifiable_type: 'Reference')`

  - `Reference(id: 1, verification_id: 1)`
  - `Reference(id: 2, verification_id: 1)`
- `Verification(id: 2, verifiable_type: 'Degree')`

  - `Degree(id: 1, verification_id: 2)`
  - `Degree(id: 2, verification_id: 2)`

I was hoping for something as simple as a dynamic `:class_name` option on the the `has_many`:

```rb
class Verification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :verifiables, class_name: -> { dynamic_class_name }
end
```

I am 99% sure that the reverse associations would actually work out of the box. So, using the records from above, the following should be no problem:

```rb
class Reference < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :verification
end

class Degree < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :verification
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add any more details about your domain logic? Why does a single `Verification` instance need to reference multiple verifiables? You may end up needing a intermediate model that has a one-to-one association with a verification and a verifiable — I don't think ActiveRecord provides this sort of functionality.

Comment: The verification object serves as a placeholder for the objects begin verified. It could be `1`, it could be `4`. The app has many different things that can be verified and all verifications will be handled through `/verify/:type/:access_code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 has_many :verifiables, class_name: -> { dynamic_class_name }
```

replace it with

```
 def self.varifiables(type)
   where(verifiable_type: type)
 end
```